# SwiftUI List data update from destination view causes unexpected behaviour

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have this rather common situation where a `List` is displaying some items from an `@ObservedObject` data store as `NavigationLinks`.

On selecting a `NavigationLink` a **DetailView** is presented. This view has a simple `Toggle` conected to a `@Published` var on its **ViewModel** class.

When the **DetailView** appears (`onAppear:`) its View Model sets the published `var` that controls the `Toggle` to `true` and also triggers an async request that will update the **main data store**, causing the `List` in the previous screen to update too.

The problem is that when this happens (the `List` is reloaded from an action triggered in the Detail View) multiple instances of the DetailViewModel seem to retained and the DetailView starts receiving events from the wrong **Publishers**.

In the first time the Detail screen is reached the behaviour is correct (as shown in the code below), the toggle is set to `true` and the **store** is updated, however, on navigating back to the `List` and then again to another DetailView the toggle is set to `true` on appearing but this time when the code that reloads the **store** executes, the toggle is set back to `false`.

My understanding is that when the `List` is reloaded and a new DetailView and ViewModel are created (as the destination of the `NavigationLink`) the initial value from the `isOn`  variable that controls the `Toggle` (which is `false`) is somehow triggering an update to the `Toggle` of the currently displayed screen.

Am I missing something here?

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Store: ObservableObject {
    static var shared: Store = .init()
    @Published var items = ["one", "two"]
    private init() { }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var store = Store.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(store.items, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(item, destination: ItemDetailView())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ItemDetailViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("A toggle", isOn: $viewModel.isOn)
            Text(viewModel.title)
            Spacer()
        }   .onAppear(perform: viewModel.onAppear)
    }
}

class ItemDetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var store: Store = .shared
    @Published var isOn = false

    var title: String {
        store.items[0]
    }
    
    func onAppear() {
        isOn = true
        asyncOperationThatUpdatesTheStoreData()
    }
    
    private func asyncOperationThatUpdatesTheStoreData() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
            self?.store.items = ["three", "four"]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're controlling lifetimes and objects in a way that's not a pattern in this UI framework. The VieModel is not going to magically republish a singleton value type; it's going to instantiate with that value and then mutate its state without ever checking in with the shared instance again, unless it is rebuilt.

```swift
class Store: ObservableObject {
    static var shared: Store = .init()

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var store = Store.shared
```

```
struct ItemDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ItemDetailViewModel()

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [String] = Store.shared.items
```

There are lots of potential viable patterns. For example:

1. Create `class RootStore: ObservableObject` and house it as an @StateObject in App. The lifetime of a StateObject is the lifetime of that view hierarchy's lifetime. You can expose it (a) directly to child views by .environmentObject(store) or (b) create a container object, such as Factory that vends ViewModels and pass that via the environment without exposing the store to views, or (c) do both a and b.
2. If you reference the store in another class, hold a weak reference `weak var store: Store?`. If you keep state in that RootStore on @Published, then you can subscribe directly to that publisher or to the RootStore's own ObjectWillChangePublisher. You could also use other Combine publishers like CurrentValueSubject to achieve the same as @Published.

For code examples, see

[Setting a StateObject value from child view causes NavigationView to pop all views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453082/setting-a-stateobject-value-from-child-view-causes-navigationview-to-pop-all-vie/67453323#67453323)

[SwiftUI @Published Property Being Updated In DetailView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729293/swiftui-published-property-being-updated-in-detailview/65730729#65730729)